# flocssについて

Tags: css

flocssを使っているのですが、
そのサイト固有のcss（margin、padding、width、color）OOCSSのストラクチャに似ている？
と
どのサイトでも共通であろうcss（あまり正直ないですが、display:blockなどでしょうか？）
両方が一つの要素にあると思いますが、
どのように分けるていますか？

例えば.c-btn　.p-btn-skinないしはp-skinのようにしますか？
しかし、同じ要素なのにc-とp-では管理しにくくないですか？

.c-btn　.c-btn-skinもありですが、c-にはskinはつけないほうが良いと谷氏が言っていましたので、
管理しやすいがどうなのかなと思ってしまいます。

一体プロはどうしてますか？
再利用もいいかと思ったのですが、無駄なクラスやcssが残ってしまったり、
どのクラスを削除していいか迷ったり、いろいろ問題がありますよね。

Answer (score 1):

[FLOCSS](https://github.com/hiloki/flocss)のページにも記載がありますが、
再利用可能なパターンはComponent、プロジェクト固有のものに関してはProject、それ以外の便利スタイルをUtilityに分類します。

管理できるように自分やプロジェクトチーム単位で決めるのが一番ですが、
迷った場合はProjectとして登録しておき、ある程度繰り返し登場するパターンだと判断したら逐一Componentとして登録し直すという形にしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Componentを育てるという意識で初めは運用していくと、そのうち落ち着くかと思います。